# How expensive are Java (Solr) thread dumps?

Tags: java, solr

As part of some ongoing maintenance, we have been taking regular thread dumps for all threads in the JVM at a one minute interval. (E.g. `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/threaddump.jsp`)

What are the performance / other negative impacts of continuing this practice indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, JVM thread dumps are cheap, low impacting, regardless of the applications. Jmap -histos on the other hand, can be very performance impacting. I work in maintance, we do a lot of thread dumps, never seen a direct crash caused by thread dumping.

The only problem with running dumps once a minute is too much information.

Are you appending the dump to a separate file? In my experience you have to look at dumps over time to catch things like transient lock contention.

Comment: I think at this point we're just planning on parsing and writing out thread counts (and maybe types) to a log file and alerting on wide deviations.

Comment: Keep an eye on the threads, waiting to lock, if you're going to have serious lock contention, that's the how to spot it. Of course, some lock contention is normal. Cheers.

Comment: We DO got a reproducible jvm crashes, when 5-minutes a threaddump periodically. After one day no more than two, jvm process crash. The process has some threads-leaking, which threads can go to 3500. But without the threaddump, it runs well with leaking. Can thread-leaking cause threaddump crashes JVM?